# root directory (External Storage) in Android 11

Tags: android, kotlin, android-11

[Mobile ScreenShot Android 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OznNe.jpg) How to create a folder on the root directory (External Storage) in Android 11 or Android R (Kotlin)
Currently able to create an App folder in Public Directory e.g DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, but not able to create an App folder in File Explorer on the root. What would be the solution?

val relativePath = "${DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS}${File.separator}${"AppName"}"

Answer (score 2):

> How to create a folder on the root directory (External Storage) in Android 11 or Android R (Kotlin)

That is no longer supported.

> What would be the solution ?

Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree` and let the *user* decide where on the *user's* device (or the *user's* chosen cloud storage provider) that the *user* would like for you to store the *user's* content. You can use `takePersistableUriPermission()` to get durable access to this tree, so you only need to prompt the user once.

Comment: I want to save images, audio, video files in a root app folder like WhatsApp. but not able to create app folder in a root directory

Comment: @ShehrozAli: "I want to save images, audio, video files in a root app folder like WhatsApp" -- WhatsApp will no longer be able to do that on many devices, as of November, when they will be forced to raise their `targetSdkVersion` to 30. It is possible that they can continue to use this directory on devices where their app is pre-installed.

Comment: According to your mentioned way android 11 still does not allow to create of a folder on the root...kindly see this link below
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files

Comment: @ShehrozAli: I never said that it did. I did say that it puts the user in control over where the content gets stored.

Comment: can you please provide any helping material to fix this issue...any tutorial?